# How to get count of records from join table with matching ID in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, forms, model-view-controller, has-many-through

I have 2 models. Meal and Food. A meal can have many food items and a food item can be a part of many meals. They have a many-to-many association, done by has_many :through. The join model is called MealFood and the join table is called meal_foods.
When creating a meal you can add as many food items as you want. There's a jQuery button that when you click it automatically appends a new input in the form and you enter the food item there.
How can I make the edit view for the meal to show as many input fields with the name of the food item as there really is.

**Meals Controller:**

```
def create
    @meal = current_user.meals.new(meal_params)

    if @meal.save
        @meal.update(total_calories: @meal.calc_total_calories, total_carbohydrates:    @meal.calc_total_carbohydrates, total_proteins: @meal.calc_total_proteins, total_fat: @meal.calc_total_fat)

        redirect_to @meal
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def edit
    @meal = Meal.find(params[:id])
end


def update
    if @meal.update(meal_params)
        @meal.update(total_calories: @meal.calc_total_calories, 
        total_carbohydrates: @meal.calc_total_carbohydrates,
        total_proteins: @meal.calc_total_proteins,
        total_fat: @meal.calc_total_fat)

        redirect_to @meal
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end
```

**Meals View (create action):**

```
<%= form_for(@meal) do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :meal_type %>
        <%= f.select :meal_type, ["Breakfast", "Lunch", "Dinner", "Morning Snack", "Afternoon Snack", "Evening Snack"] %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <label class="input-dropdown">Food Item #1</label>
        <%= select_tag "meal[food_ids][]", options_from_collection_for_select(Food.all, "id", "name") %>
    </div>

    <div class="field submit">
        <%= f.submit class: "button button-highlight button-block" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe it is better to use multiselect here? There is a good plugin for it - select2 - https://github.com/argerim/select2-rails

Comment: Try it out this [cocoon gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this uses a join table, I assume you don't want users to actually be able to edit the `Food` record itself - they should be editing the `MealFood` record, right?

In that case, you should be able to query meal.meal_foods to get the join table records you want to edit. Your query might look something like this:

```
@meal_foods = @meal.meal_foods.includes(:food)
```

The `.includes(:food)` will auto-load all the food records you need, preventing you from having an N+1 query problem.

Then in your view, you can do something like this:

```
<div class="field">
  <% @meal_foods.each do |mf| %>
    <... your input element for each record />
  <% end %>
</div>
```

If you do want your users to be able to modify the `Food` records themselves, then you can use the same strategy, but just use the `through` association you already created.